# How can I transpose string ? do I need to use 2d array?

Tags: java, arrays

I have string array which I enter with scanner like

```
 12345
 12345
```

I wanna transpose this like

```
 11
 22
 33
 44
 55
```

which ways I should use to code.

Comment: What did you try already?

Comment: ı will try ı am adding strings to array with scanner they should be same lenght for transpose but ı dont know how to transpose them

Comment: Ok that's clear but please post the code you've already produced.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following steps:

- Make a loop, and go through each character of the String.
- Create a new String by concatenating the character(i-th) of both strings in each iteration.
- Store the resultant strings in an `ArrayList<String>` if you want.